# Angular.js square root for this calculator

Tags: angularjs

I have searched far and wide looking for a simplified square root short code version  and found plenty of versions in JavaScript, Java, jQuery ... but nothing in Angular.js.

Below is my code:

```
<body align"center"><form><h1 align="center">Quick 2 number Angular.js Calculator </h1></center>
<center><h6>- Teaching aide only -</h6></center>
    <div ng-app="">

    <input type="number" ng-model="numb1" placeholder="number1" size="5px"><br />

    <input type="number" ng-model="numb2" placeholder="number2" size="5px"><br />

<b style="color:#0000FF"><button disabled>+</button>
<button disabled>-</button> 
<button disabled>X</button> 
<button disabled>/</button></b>
<button style="background-color:lime;color:green" disabled>ENT</button>
<button style="background-color:orange;color:red">CLR</button>
<center><h2>Answers Below</h2></center>

 <p>My first expression: {{ numb1 }} ; {{ numb2 }}</p>

 <p>Addition: {{ numb1 + numb2 }}</p>
 <p>Subtraction: {{ numb1 - numb2 }}</p>
 <p>Multiplication: {{ numb1 * numb2 }}</p>
 <p>Division: {{ numb1 / numb2 }}</p>

 <p>Square of {{ numb1 }}<small><sup>2</sup></small> is {{ numb1 * numb1 }}<br>Square of {{ numb2 }}<small><sup>2</sup></small> is {{ numb2 * numb2 }}</p>
 <p>Cube of {{ numb1 }}<small><sup>3</sup></small> is {{ numb1 * numb1 * numb1 }}<br>Cube of {{ numb2 }}<small> 
 <sup>3</sup></small> is {{ numb2 * numb2 * numb2 }}</p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to use filter for this:

```js
angular.module('app', []).filter('sqrt', function() {
   return function(number) {
      return Math.sqrt(number);
   };
});
```

```html
<div ng-app="app">
  <input type="number" ng-model="numb1" placeholder="number1" size="5px"><br />
  <div>{{ numb1 | sqrt }}</div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.2/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Jcubic you are probably the closest to the answer I'm looking for can you refine this for input of numb1 ~

Comment: @brofarops it's just variable name change, it don't change the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, javascript has what you want.  You need to pass an argument to the Math.sqrt function for this.  Here is an example from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/sqrt).  You could create a service or a directive to wrap around this function, but angularjs itself doesn't have this function.

```
function calcHypotenuse(a, b) {
  return(Math.sqrt((a * a) + (b * b)));
}

console.log(calcHypotenuse(3, 4));
// expected output: 5

console.log(calcHypotenuse(5, 12));
// expected output: 13

console.log(calcHypotenuse(0, 0));
// expected output: 0
```

If you have to create a custom solution, I would recommend looking at the javascript code for the function itself to see how it's implemented.  You can go to [Firefox](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/) for example, to download their implementation.

I was able to find the algorithm, but not the code there after I downloaded it.

> Square Root
>
> A simple iterative algorithm is used to compute the greatest integer
>   less than or equal to the square root.  Essentially, this is Newton's
>   linear approximation, computed by finding successive values of the
>   equation:
>
> ```
>       x[k]^2 - V x[k+1]    =  x[k] - ------------
>            2 x[k]
> ```
>
> ...where V is the value for which the square root is being sought.  In
>   essence, what is happening here is that we guess a value for the
>   square root, then figure out how far off we were by squaring our guess
>   and subtracting the target.  Using this value, we compute a linear
>   approximation for the error, and adjust the "guess".  We keep doing
>   this until the precision gets low enough that the above equation
>   yields a quotient of zero.  At this point, our last guess is one
>   greater than the square root we're seeking.
>
> The initial guess is computed by dividing V by 4, which is a heuristic
>   I have found to be fairly good on average.  This also has the
>   advantage of being very easy to compute efficiently, even for large
>   values.
>
> So, the resulting algorithm works as follows:
>
> ```
> x = V / 4   /* compute initial guess */
>
> loop  t = (x * x) - V   /* Compute absolute error  */     u = 2 * x         /* Adjust by tangent slope */     t = t / u
> ```
>
> /* Loop is done if error is zero */     if(t == 0)
>         break
>
> /* Adjust guess by error term    */     x = x - t
>       end
>
> ```
> x = x - 1
> ```
>
> The result of the computation is the value of x.

Comment: James I appreciate your response but I'm trying to keep it all Angular.js ~ I did do the JavaScript version but again it isn't Angular.js as per my assignment...

Comment: Ahh, then you need to add the homework tag to this question.

Comment: How do you do that ??? This really is not an academic course homework assignment but client's specs...

Comment: Okay, sounded like a homework assignment to me.  Would you elaborate the use case?  Why reinvent the wheel when a solution is already present in javascript?  I don't see the point.

Comment: James " ...but angularjs itself doesn't have this function. " is the exact problem I ran into while searching thus the reason for the question.

Answer (score 0):

**In Html :**
call the cube and square function defined in angular controller

```
<input type="number" ng-model="numb1" placeholder="number1" ng-change="cube(numb1)" size="5px"><br />

<p>Square of {{ numb1 }}<small><sup>2</sup></small> is {{ cubeResult }}</p>
```

**In Controller(*.js) :**

define a function that returns square and cube of particular value

```
  $scope.cubeResult =0;
  $scope.square= function(value){
       $scope.cubeResult = value * value;
  };

  $scope.cube = function(value){
       $scope.cubeResult = value * value * value;
  };
```

Comment: The program already squares and cubes but as far as getting the Math.sqrt{{ numb1 }} or answering individuallly what the sqrt of {{ numb1 }} and doing the same for {{ numb2 }}